# Cron Job for WordPress on siteground

Tags: wordpress, cron

I needs some help please, I am trying to set up a CRON job in the Cpanel of my Siteground hosting with the following string with the admin username and password for my WordPress install.

```
 /usr/local/bin/php ~/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php -s http://www.promedical.com.vu -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD -e Job -a execute
```

However is keep getting "`ERROR: Invalid username and/or password<!-- deferred 0 scripts, deferred 0 styles & minified html in 0 seconds -->`"

I have checked both multiple time and the username and password are correct, I am not where to from here?

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you made sure that there are no reserved or unsafe URL characters in your username or password. These include:& = + $ ? % , / : { } | ' #

See also 'Managing Scheduled Jobs' at https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs#ManagingScheduledJobs-PHPclimethod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Siteground I use the wp-cli method as I find that more reliable:

```
/usr/bin/wp --user=USERNAME --url=https://EXAMPLE.ORG --path=/home/CPUSER/public_html --timezone="PHPTZ" civicrm api job.execute auth=0
```

replace CPUSER with the cpanel username , USERNAME with your WP Username, make sure the url is your site's canonical url and set the php timezone (eg America/New_York)

you may have to login via ssh and do a `which -a wp` to dtermine the path to the wp-cli script.  It's always been `/usr/bin/wp` for me, but I would double check

Comment: thanks that seemed to work, most of the jobs run but now i get an error should I ask it in a different question?

Comment: I would think another question would be appropriate